# How to understand the recursiveness of this function?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, recursion

This is a program to find the least number of characters that should be inserted (at any position) to convert the given string into a palindrome. Can somebody explain to me what goes on more in detail inside the palindrome function? I have a hard time understanding the recursive function being called again inside the else condition. Thank you!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int min(int a, int b) 
{ 
    if(a > b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
} 

int palindrome(char string[], int l, int h) 
{
    if (l >= h)
        return 0; 
    if(string[l] == string[h])
        return palindrome(string, l+1, h-1);
    else
    {
        int choice1 = 1 + palindrome(string, l+1, h);
        int choice2 = 1 + palindrome(string, l, h-1);
        return min(choice1, choice2);
    }  
} 

int main() 
{ 
    char string[20];
    printf("ENTER STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("%d", palindrome(string, 0, strlen(string) - 1)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion* (sorry, couldn't resist :)

Comment: Sadly, it does not work properly. When I give it `wewtrert` it prints `3` as the shortest palindrome (arguably should be `1`). When I give it `ewtrert` it prints `2` as the shortest palindrome, but that would require a double letter to be present. When I give it `wocteyr` it prints `6` as the shortest length. It seems to be attempting to find a palindrome with both ends cropped, the left cropped, and then the right.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the question is not to find the length of the longest embedded palindrome, but rather to find the fewest number of characters that need to be added in in order to make the original string a palindrome.

Comment: @WeatherVane As mentioned, I am trying to find the least amount of characters you can insert to make a world palindromic. Suppose you have the word "mykma" you should add a letter "a" in front of 'm' and "k" in front of 'y' so in the end you have "amkykma" which is a palindrome. So, the least number of characters to make "mykma" palindromic is 2. Hope this clears it.

Comment: @usr I see what you did there ;) But hey, give me a break I am new to this stuff :D

Comment: @c0mp13x as you should see from my comment under one answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane we are all trying to learn here :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code solves the following problem:

> You are given a string. How few characters must you insert into it to make it a palindrome?

There's a nice set of observations we can make to solve this problem. For starters, note that any string of length zero or one is already a palindrome. As a result, if we're asked to add characters to a string of length zero or one, then we don't need to add any characters in at all. We already have a palindrome! That gives us our base case:

> **Base Case**: Any string of length zero or one requires no added characters to make a palindrome.

Let's suppose that, instead, we have two or more characters in our string. For it to be a palindrome, its first and last characters must match one another - otherwise, it's not a palindrome. Lots of *other* things have to happen for our string to become a palindrome, but certainly if the first and last characters don't match, we're in trouble.

So let's begin by looking at the first and last characters of our string. Either they match, or they don't. In the case where they match, we're in good shape! We won't need to add any specific characters to specifically get those two characters to match one another. At that point, all we have to do is make sure that the remaining characters - the ones on the inside - match one another. That gives us another simple case to consider:

> **Recursive Case 1:** If the first and last character of the string match, pretend they aren't there, and then recursively figure out how many characters are needed to make the middle characters of the string a palindrome.

On the other hand, we may have a string where the first and last characters don't match. That means that we're looking, schematically, at a string that looks something like this:

> `a - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b`

Now, what has to happen to make this string a palindrome? Well, we're going to have to insert at least one character in order to make things match, since we need to get the first and last character to be the same. There are two different ways that we can do this, though. The first option would be to append an **a** to the end of the string, like this:

> `a - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b` **a**

If we did put an **a** here, then, using the above rule, we'd say that the first and last characters match, so we could drop the first and last character and look at what's left:

> `- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b`

The net effect of this is that we've essentially discarded the first character of the string (the original **a**) by adding one more character to the string. From here, we'd want to do whatever is best to make the rest of the string a palindrome.

The other option would be to put a **b** in the front of the string:

> **b** `a - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b`

Here, we can match this new **b** and the old one, giving this:

> `a - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -`

That's required us to add in one character, and then we'd like to (recursively, of course) figure out the fewest number of characters that need to be added to the rest of the string to make it a palindrome.

Overall, this gives us the following rule:

> **Recursive Case 2:** If the first and last characters don't match, then we need to add in one more character, either at the front or the back, to make them match. So try dropping the first character of the string and seeing the best way to proceed from there, then drop the last character of the string and see the best option from there, and take whichever option is better. Don't forget to add 1 for the character we inserted!

Now that you've seen this description, can you map this base case and the two recursive steps onto the code that you've shared with us?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get the problem.

Comment: @templatetypedef I understand the idea I just don't understand how the implementation on these two:
`int choice1 = 1 + palindrome(string, l+1, h);
int choice2 = 1 + palindrome(string, l, h-1);`

is done.

Comment: Confirming: is your question how the recursion works when two different recursive calls are made, rather than just one?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, exactly!

Comment: Great answer. @c0mp13x An [illustration](https://img.vivaolinux.com.br/imagens/artigos/comunidade/ArvoresBinarias_recursao_fibonacci.png) on multiple recursive functions might help you. It's in portuguese, but you will be able to see the stack trace. The function is `double fib (double n)
{
return (n == 0 || n == 1) ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}`

Comment: I wish I could give a simple explanation of branching recursion here, but that’s something my students usually need at least a week’s worth of examples and animations to digest. I agree with Enzo’s suggestion to look at simpler examples first. Seeing how the Fibonacci sequence gets computed is a great example.

Comment: @templatetypedef I see :/ well maybe I am just moving a bit too fast and should take things slower with recursion. I loved your explanation. Made it easier than anything else on the web. @ EnzoFerber thank you for the schematic, I'm on it right now. 
Do any of you have any PDF literature online I can study to progress my knowledge a bit more?